# plus minus accordion clickable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
    ## Clickable plus minus accordion ##
```

---

I have html of accordion clickable only plus minus, want collapse on plus minus button click its working on first level only but i want also on second level i am trying but its not working suggest me where i m wrong here is the link where i selected the example please see that link also for more info 
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/full-clickable-panel-heading

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .clickable
  {
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  .clickable .glyphicon
  {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 6px 12px;
   border-radius: 4px
  }

  .panel-heading span
  {
   margin-top: -23px;
   font-size: 15px;
   margin-right: -9px;
  }
  a.clickable { color: inherit; }
  a.clickable:hover { text-decoration:none; }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
       <h3 class="panel-title">
        core service
       </h3>
       <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
       <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">
          Panel 3
         </h3>
        <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
         Panel content</div>
        </div>
       
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    
  </body>
  <script>
  $(document).on('click', '.panel-heading span.clickable', function (e) {
   var $this = $(this);
   if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
    $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
    $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
    $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
   } else {
    $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
    $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
    $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
   }
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.panel div.clickable', function (e) {
   var $this = $(this);
   if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
    $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
    $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
    $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
   } else {
    $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
    $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
    $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
   }
  });
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.panel-heading span.clickable').click();
   $('.panel div.clickable').click();
  });

  </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: Currently you're only applying js for the 1st level parent which leads to the behavior you are currently viewing. What You need to do is apply the js for the parent's parent's BOTH childs. Aka panel 1 and panel 2.

Comment: so what should i do for the second level ??

Comment: I am sure the code is very self explanatory that you will not need help. If you still can't find it I will post the solution

Comment: i need solution coz m trying lots of time but i stuck in js

Comment: @Sagar is there any solution